Could scipy.optimize.minimize be suitable for multi-objectives?
The current model is built using the manner of scipy.optimize.minimize, and now the business needs to transform the model into a multi-objective optimization model. I searched the document of scipy(version==1.1.3), but I did not find cases or statements of multi-objective optimization. Can minimize support multi-objective optimization? If so, how to coding?

The answer depends on your goal and the underlying model. Schemes like weighted-sum and lexicographic optimization can be implemented on top of standard single-objective solvers.
